# Printing dictionary key-value pairs with placeholder string

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

I am trying to write a program which will outputs as shown below:

```
father is repeated 2 times
where is repeated 1 time
art is repeated 1 time
are is repeated 1 time
thou is repeated 1 time
```

This is what I have for now:

```
x = input('Please enter a string: ').lower()
def counter():
    counts = dict()
    words = str.split(x)

    for word in words:
        if word in counts:
            counts[word] += 1
        else:
            counts[word] = 1
            print(counts)
    return counts

counter()
```

It prints out like this:

```
   Please enter a string:  father father where art are thou
   {'father': 2, 'where': 1, 'art': 1, 'are': 1, 'thou': 1}
```

How can I print out the data in the format as shown above?

Comment: There's no need to keep editing your posts. It is fine in the format it is in currently.

Comment: please correct your indentation of the function in your code while formatting

Comment: Note that your for loop can be optimized. Replace all the ifs with `counts [word] = words.count (word)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addressing your original question, use a placeholder string and insert values using `str.format`. The return value of `counter()` must be captured in a variable, say `counts`.

```
placeholder = '{} is repeated {} time{}'

counts = counter()
for k, v in counts.items():
    print(placeholder.format(k, v, 's' if v > 1 else ''))
```

```
father is repeated 2 times
where  is repeated 1 time
art    is repeated 1 time
are    is repeated 1 time
thou   is repeated 1 time
```

(The output isn't actually aligned like this, I just fixed it here so it preys less on my OCD.)

As an improvement, you can use the `collections.Counter` object to do this quite simply:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(x.lower().split())
```

Now, repeat the loop as above.

Comment: What happened to L? :(

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Hmm, feeling a little mad scientist-y these days ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
string = "Father father where art are thou"
new_list = string.lower().split()
get_value = Counter(new_list)
get_char_s = lambda x :'s' if x > 1 else ''
for k, v in get_value.items():
    print '%s is repeated %d time%s' % (k,v, get_char_s(v))
>>>thou is repeated 1 time
   where is repeated 1 time
   art is repeated 1 time
   father is repeated 2 times
   are is repeated 1 time
```

Comment: Why a map? You could just do `x.lower().split()`.

Comment: Also, this doesn't answer the question, OP wants to _print_ the output in the format. They already have the code to count words.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thanks for pointing out the things which i left out.Now I have optimized my code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use OrderedDict in order to sort the dict object as per your requirement.

As this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import itemgetter

x = raw_input('Please enter a string: ').lower()#raw input for string to improve parsing.
def counter():
    counts = dict()
    words = str.split(x)

    for word in words:
        if word in counts:
            counts[word] += 1
        else:
            counts[word] = 1
    print(counts)
    d = OrderedDict(sorted(counts.items(), key=itemgetter(1),reverse =True))#Ordered Dict for sorting in reverse of keys like you like.
    print d
    return d

counter()

Output:
OrderedDict([('father', 2), ('thou', 1), ('where', 1), ('art', 1), ('are', 1)])
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question either. This is a question of printing, not counting.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks, i have changed my answer as per your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

i think give some modification on the code should also works using string format, ike this :

```
def counter():
    ...:     counts = dict()
    ...:     words = str.split(x)
    ...:     for word in words:
    ...:         if word in counts:
    ...:             counts[word] += 1
    ...:         else:
    ...:             counts[word] = 1
    ...:     print('father is repeated {counts[father]}\n \
    ...:             art is repeated {counts[art]}\n \
    ...:             are is repeated {counts[are]}\n \
    ...:             thou is repeated {counts[thou]}\n'.format(counts=counts))
```